# Update bridge entities in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions

The problem that I haven't been able to figure out is updating bridge entities. For example, I have the following diagram,
[image]

How should I update student enrolments given that there might be multiple update queries at the same time such as

- Currently, student 1 is enrolling to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- [query] Making student 1 enrol to units 1, 2, 5, 6, 7
- [query] Making student 1 enrol to units 1, 3, 5, 7, 8

The expected result is either:

- Student 1 enrolling to units 1, 2, 5, 6, 7
- Or student 1 enrolling to units 1, 3, 5, 7, 8

For these updates, there are two ways I could think of to make those updates

1. Delete all enrolments of student 1 and insert new enrolments to student 1.
2. Find out what are the changes, then insert the new enrolments and remove the removed enrolments.

The problem is that I can think of so many complicated situations that might mess up the result that I don't know what to do anymore.

- Can I use the transaction system to resolve this situation and how does it work?
- What are the normal ways to resolve concurrent connections like this in production.

I would really appreciate it if you can give me a detailed explanation on this or a link to any kind of resources that can help me understand and resolve this situation.

Comment: Such inconsistent changes to the data is not programmatic but administrative problem.

Comment: I suppose student can enroll for different units in different time periods(semesters?) so I would hold the time period in the bridging table.

Comment: @P.Salmon let just keep the scenario simple. What I want to ask is about updating the bridge entities.

Comment: @Akina can you explain more? What do you mean by administrative problems?

Comment: I mean that the rules for working with data should exclude the described situations. In the described case, only a person can decide which final version of the two theoretically possible should be obtained (moreover, it is actually possible that the final state should partially include changes from both sources).